# Jquery:how to get the location of each anchor link?

Tags: jquery

How can i get location/position for each of these `<a name="link1"></a> , <a name="link2"></a>` etc etc

for example when i click on `<a href="#link1">link1</a>`

i want to get the location/position on the page, ie the value of `<a name="link1"></a>`  and so forth.

I have the following code , i want to get the position value**(eg top =500px)** of `<a name="link1"></a>` , `<a name="link2"></a>`etc  in the page and pass it on here

```
$('ul#mainNav li a').click(function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    if($(this).attr('href') !== '#'){
        var location = $($(this).attr('href')).offset().top - 150; /* For your header height, subtract 150 or whatever it ends up being */
        $('html, body').animate({scrollTop: location}, 600);
    } else {
        $('html, body').animate({scrollTop: 0}, 600);
    }
});

<div id="wrapper">

    <div id="branding">
    <h1>Branding</h1>
    <ul id="mainNav"> 
    <li class="first"><a href="#">Home</a></li> 
    <li><a href="#link1">link1</a></li> 
    <li><a href="#link2">link2</a></li> 
    <li><a href="#link3">link3</a></li> 

    </ul> 

    </div> 

    <div id="content"> 



        <div id="form-b">

        <form id="comments_form" action="#" method="post">

    <fieldset>
      <legend>Your Contact Details  Link1 <a name="link1"></a> </legend>

      <p>
      <label for="author">Name: <span class="required">(Required)</span></label>
      <input name="author" id="author" type="text" />
      </p>

      <p>
      <label for="email">Email Address: <span class="feedback">Incorrect email address. Please try again.</span></label>
      <input name="email" id="email" type="text" />
      </p>

      <p>
      <label for="url">Web Address:</label>
      <input name="url" id="url" type="text" />
      </p>
    </fieldset>


    <fieldset>
      <legend>Your Contact Details  Link 2<a name="link2"></a> </legend>
      <p>
      <label for="author">Name: <span class="required">(Required)</span></label>
      <input name="author" id="author" type="text" />
      </p>

      <p>
      <label for="email">Email Address: <span class="feedback">Incorrect email address. Please try again.</span></label>
      <input name="email" id="email" type="text" />
      </p>

      <p>
      <label for="url">Web Address:</label>
      <input name="url" id="url" type="text" />
      </p>
    </fieldset>
    <fieldset>
      <legend>Your Contact Details  Link 3<a name="link3"></a></legend>
      <p>
      <label for="author">Name: <span class="required">(Required)</span></label>
      <input name="author" id="author" type="text" />
      </p>

      <p>
      <label for="email">Email Address: <span class="feedback">Incorrect email address. Please try again.</span></label>
      <input name="email" id="email" type="text" />
      </p>

      <p>
      <label for="url">Web Address:</label>
      <input name="url" id="url" type="text" />
      </p>
    </fieldset>

    <fieldset>
      <legend>Your Contact Details  </legend>
      <p>
      <label for="author">Name: <span class="required">(Required)</span></label>
      <input name="author" id="author" type="text" />
      </p>

      <p>
      <label for="email">Email Address: <span class="feedback">Incorrect email address. Please try again.</span></label>
      <input name="email" id="email" type="text" />
      </p>

      <p>
      <label for="url">Web Address:</label>
      <input name="url" id="url" type="text" />
      </p>
    </fieldset>

    <fieldset id="submit-b">
      <legend>  </legend>
    <div class="wrap">  
      <p>
    <input id="submit" class="submit" name="submit" type="submit"/>
    </p>
    </div>
    </fieldset>

    </form>


        </div>

    </div> 



    <div id="footer">
    <p>Footer</p>
    </div>


    </div>
```

Comment: What do you mean by location?

Comment: Do you mean the position on the page, or the href?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are referring to the actual position, you could use the `position` method in jQuery (http://api.jquery.com/position/), like this:

```
$(document).on("click", "a", function () {
    var pos = $("[name='" + $(this).attr('href').replace("#", '') + "']").position();
    alert("left = " + pos.left + ", top = " + pos.top);
});
```

jsfiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/hZJPw/

Answer (score 0):

If you are referring "href" as the location, you can get that by

```
$("a").click(function() {
  alert($(this).attr('href'));
});
```

Answer (score -1):

```
<li><a href="#link1">link1</a></li> 
<li><a href="#link2">link2</a></li> 
<li><a href="#link3">link3</a></li>
```

then in your html code.

```
<div id="#link1"> Duis autem vel eum iriure </div>

<div id="#link2"> Duis autem vel eum iriure </div>

<div id="#link3"> Duis autem vel eum iriure </div>
```

this is the structure used there. so click on link1 go to id="#link1"